# pass array with urls into template

Tags: python, django

Here I got the right URLs

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
import requests

def main(request):
    return render(request,'main.html')

req = requests.get('https://d3.ru/api/posts').json()
arr = []
for data in req['posts']:
    urls = data['main_image_url']
    if urls != None:
        arr.append(urls)
print('urls',arr)
```

How can i pass array `arr` into my template `main.html` into `<img class>`

```
{% extends "wrapper.html" %}
{% block title %}
<div class="container">
    <img class = "col-12 ml-auto col-12 mr-auto" src=///arr???>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass your list as an argument in `render` ant then loop over it in the template

**Ex:**

*Views.py*

```
def main(request):
    req = requests.get('https://d3.ru/api/posts').json()
    arr = []
    for data in req['posts']:
        urls = data['main_image_url']
        if urls != None:
            arr.append(urls)
    print('urls', arr)
    return render(request, 'main.html', {'arr': arr})
```

*And Template*

```
{% extends "wrapper.html" %}
{% block title %}
<div class="container">
    {% for i in arr %}
        <img class = "col-12 ml-auto col-12 mr-auto" src={{ i }}>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
{% endblock %}
```